# SAP FB03 with custom item selection

Tags: document, abap, sap-erp

I've some documents with hundreds of records (items). I'm designing a report to present some data to the final user. 
The user is presented with an ALV with information of such items. 
I've already coded the call of FB03 transaction so that when the line is clicked, the corresponding document (the document that has that item line) is shown with a callback user command in the ALV.

The last step that I don't seem to get information about is, whether it is possible to open the FB03 with call transaction with a desired record selected, instead of showing the document with the first item highlighted. I desire to show the document and having highlighted a different record (namely, the one associated with the clicked row of the ALV).

Is that in anyway possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a MWE so that it's easier to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of FB03 you can call FB09D. Here you can input the line item number and take the user directly to line item display.